# why is my sign up function not working in ASP.NET?

Tags: c#, asp.net, 3-tier

Working on the 3-tier architecture in C# ASP.net

Initially i retrieve all the asp.net attributes from the c-sharp page.

```
protected void Register_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        String fname = this.firstname.Text;
        String lname = this.lastname.Text;
        String username = this.username.Text;
        String address = this.address.Text;
        String gender = this.gender.Text;
        String age = this.age.Text;
        String pwd = this.password.Text;
        String cpwd = this.cpassword.Text;
        String secQ = this.secQ.Text;
        String secA = this.secA.Text;

        UserOp userop = new UserOp();

        if (userop.signup(fname, lname, username, address, gender, age, pwd, secQ, secA))
        {
            Response.Redirect("home.aspx");
        }
        else
        {
            Response.Redirect("index.aspx");
        }


    }
```

And the second layer will consist of the following method

```
 public bool signup(String fname,String lname,String username,String address,String gender,String age,
                String password, String secQ, String secA)
    {
        user = new User(fname,lname,username,address,gender,age,password,secQ,secA);

        userdata.addUser(user);
        return true;
    }
```

Finally the data access layer will consist of the sql part which adds the user to the database.

```
 private SqlConnection con;
    private SqlDataAdapter sda;
    private SqlCommand command;
    private SqlDataReader sdr;


    public UserData()
    {
        con = new SqlConnection("Data Source=WIN-5KGBCLFK1FJ;Initial Catalog=thedb;Integrated Security=True");
        sda = new SqlDataAdapter();
    }


    public Boolean addUser(User user)
    {



       try
       {
       //    con.Open();
           sda.InsertCommand = new SqlCommand("INSERT INTO tbluser VALUES ('" + user.Fname + "','" + user.Lname + "','" + user.Username + "','" + user.Age + "','" + user.Sex + "','" + user.Country + "','" + user.Password + "','" + user.SecQ + "','" + user.SecA + "')", con);
           con.Open();
           sda.InsertCommand.ExecuteNonQuery();
           con.Close();
           return true;
       }
       catch (Exception ex)
       {
           throw ex;
       }

   }
```

Thinking it was something wrong with the SQL part i changed it to the following code but the same exception occurs.

```
    sda.InsertCommand = new SqlCommand ("INSERT INTO tbluser (fName,lName,username,age,sex,country, password, secQ, secA) VALUES (@fname,@lname,@username,@age,@sex,@country,@password,@secQ,@secA)",con);
        sda.InsertCommand.Parameters.Add("@fname", SqlDbType.VarChar).Value = user.Fname;
        sda.InsertCommand.Parameters.Add("@lname", SqlDbType.VarChar).Value = user.Lname;
        sda.InsertCommand.Parameters.Add("@username", SqlDbType.VarChar).Value = user.Username;
        sda.InsertCommand.Parameters.Add("@age", SqlDbType.VarChar).Value = user.Age;
        sda.InsertCommand.Parameters.Add("@sex", SqlDbType.VarChar).Value = user.Sex;
        sda.InsertCommand.Parameters.Add("@country", SqlDbType.VarChar).Value = user.Country;
        sda.InsertCommand.Parameters.Add("@password", SqlDbType.VarChar).Value = user.Password;
        sda.InsertCommand.Parameters.Add("@secQ", SqlDbType.VarChar).Value = user.SecQ;
        sda.InsertCommand.Parameters.Add("@secA", SqlDbType.VarChar).Value = user.SecA;
        con.Open();
        sda.InsertCommand.ExecuteNonQuery();
        con.Close();
        return true;
```

> InvalidOperationException Unhanded by the User code
>   An exception of type 'System.InvalidOperationException' occurred in DataAccessLayer.dll but was not handled in user code

The user records does not seem to be adding to the database table.

Answer (score 1):

You are trying to open connection **twice** in your `addUser` method.. Remove the either of them..

```
try
{
     //con.Open(); //Not Needed
     sda.InsertCommand = new SqlCommand("INSERT INTO tbluser VALUES ('" + user.Fname + "','" + user.Lname + "','" + user.Username + "','" + user.Age + "','" + user.Sex + "','" + user.Country + "','" + user.Password + "','" + user.SecQ + "','" + user.SecA + "')", con);
     con.Open();
     sda.InsertCommand.ExecuteNonQuery();
     con.Close();
     return true;
}
```

Check Exception documentation for **[`SqlConnection.Open()`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.data.sqlclient.sqlconnection.open.aspx)**

[image: Exception Description]